# Adding a raw .txt file to a layout

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I'm trying to add a text file for a help page on my app but with the code I have it's just crashing the app when I select help from the options menu.  I know it's to do with this code as when I comment it out it opens the help page fine.

The code is in my HelpActivity class:

```
public class HelpActivity extends Activity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.help_page);
}

InputStream iFile = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.gamehelp);

private String inputStreamToString(InputStream iFile) {
    TextView helpText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHelpText);
    String strFile = inputStreamToString(iFile);
    helpText.setText(strFile);
    return strFile;
    }

}
```

Can anyone see any problem with how I'm trying to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't include any error logs, I'm judging just from your code:

```
InputStream iFile = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.gamehelp);
```

You are calling this in class body, but getResources() is not available here. What you should do is:

```
InputStream iFile;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.help_page);
    iFile = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.gamehelp);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  It has stopped it crashing but it doesn't actually show the text file

Comment: @PhilAdams I don't know about that, it's not clear from your code. But what I can suggest you is to try putting contents of your txt file into string.xml resources file. You might need it to escape it first (Google "Java escape string online"), but I guess it might be a solution for you.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try